# Login denied on Office 365 Zabbix Email notification

Tags: ubuntu, office365, zabbix

I am having "Login denied" on Office 365 Zabbix email notification. I have ubuntu server installed. My Zabbix Media configuration is as follow:

```
SMTP Server: smtp.office365.com
SMTP server port: 587
SMTP helo: companydomain.com
SMTP email: zabbixmonitoring@companydomain.com
Connection Security: STARTTLS
SSL verify peer: []
SSL verify host: []
Authentication: Normal password
Username: zabbixmonitoring@companydomain.com
Password: mypassword
Enabled [x]
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a limitation in Zabbix, reported at https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-3367 . There is also a community patch attached there.

A potential solution would be running a local MTA like Postfix which would relay emails from Zabbix and authenticate as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am unsure about where and how to install the patch you mentioned. I took different approach this time to give a shot. I changed the public IP address of Ubuntu server, just to see if it makes difference. I am getting different error this time: "Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 40001 milliseconds" I have another CentOS machine with exact Zabbix server configuration with no issue sending out Office365 email notification. Any idea to solve connection time out error? The IP address is whitelisted and firewall ports are open as in CentOS server.

Comment: With the IP address change, it now times out completely. As for the patch, you would have to apply it with the `patch` utility and recompile the Zabbix server. Are you saying that your CentOS system is able to send emails directly to Office365?

Comment: Also added a suggestion for a relaying MTA in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While trying to patch, I get this message: "File to patch:" What file or path should I use for the patch?

Comment: while I tried to apply the patch I am getting several "Hunk #1 FAILED at 32."  messages. Where can I get the latest patch for zabbix-3.2.7 version?

Comment: These are community-supplied patches, there are no guarantees and there might be no help if things break. I'd suggest evaluating a relaying MTA solution instead.